# Method of Complements in Base 17 Given a base 10 number.

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science

Given the following table which shows the symbols I am using when representing numbers in base 17.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 0_{10} &  1_{10} &  2_{10} &  3_{10} &  4_{10} &  5_{10} &  6_{10} &  7_{10} &   
 8_{10} &  9_{10} & 10_{10} & 11_{10} & 12_{10} & 13_{10} & 14_{10} & 15_{10} & 
16_{10} \\ \hline
 0_{17} &  1_{17} &  2_{17} &  3_{17} &  4_{17} &  5_{17} &  6_{17} &  7_{17} &   
 8_{17} &  9_{17} &  a_{17} &  b_{17} &  c_{17} &  d_{17} &  e_{17} &  f_{17} & 
 g_{17} \\ \hline
\end{array}

If I want to convert $-9_{10}$ to a number in base $17$ using the method of complemnts, what is the correct algorithm to do this? Currently what am doing is the following.

1. Convert $9_{10}$ to base 17 by continuously dividing $9_{10}$ by $17_{10}$ until the quotient is $0$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
 Division & Remainder \\ \hline
 9_{10} / 17_{10} & 9_{10} \\ \hline
 0_{10}           &        \\ \hline
\end{array}

2. So $9_{10} \rightarrow 9_{17}$. Now I convert $9_{17}$ to its base 17's complement using the following algorithm. I subtract it from the largest number $16_{10}$ or $g_{17}$, then I add $1$.

$$
g - 9 = 7
$$
$$
7 + 1 = 8
$$

Therefore, using what I think to be the method of complements, is $8_{17}$ the complements form of $9_{17}$? If not what is the correct algorithm to get the $17's$ complement of $-9_{10}$ in base $17$?